# Как изменить размер Entry в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

То что я хотел сделать - калькулятор. Но я не могу изменять размер Entry(ans) в tkinter и не задевая других. Если не изменить размер то Entry будет очень маленьким для калькулятора. Проверьте пожалуйста. Иначе вы просто скажите "все норм же". **Спасибо заранее**!

Вот часть кода:

```
import tkinter as tk
wn = tk.Tk()
fnt = ('Arial',18)
fr = tk.Frame(bg = 'black')
fr.grid(sticky = 'nsew')
ans = tk.Entry(master = fr,width = 4,text = '',relief = 'sunken',borderwidth = 10,bg = 'black',fg = 'white')
ans.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
def check():
    if ans.get() == '0':
        ans.delete(0,tk.END)

def b1a():
    check()
    ans.insert(tk.END,'1')
def b2a():
    check()
    ans.insert(tk.END,'2')
def b3a():
    check()
    ans.insert(tk.END,'3')

wn.resizable(width=False, height=False)
b1 = tk.Button(master = fr,text = '1',width = 4,height = 2,command = b1a,bg = 'lightgreen')# Это кнопка
b2 = tk.Button(master = fr,text = '2',width = 4,height = 2,command = b2a,bg = 'lightgreen')#Это кнопка
b3 = tk.Button(master = fr,text = '3',width = 4,height = 2,command = b3a,bg = 'lightgreen')#Это кнопка

ans.configure(font = fnt)# Это просто изменяет размер и шрифт
b1.configure(font = fnt)# Это просто изменяет размер и шрифт
b2.configure(font = fnt)# Это просто изменяет размер и шрифт
b3.configure(font = fnt)# Это просто изменяет размер и шрифт

b1.grid(padx = 3,pady = 3,row = 1,column = 0)
b2.grid(padx = 3,pady = 3,row = 1,column = 1)
b3.grid(padx = 3,pady = 3,row = 1,column = 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через параметр `columnspan` указать, чтобы текстовое поле занимало несколько колонок (3 в данном случае) и добавить `sticky='ew'`, чтобы оно расширялось на всю доступную ширину:

```
ans.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')
```

Результат:

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Можешь поменять размер поля ввода с помощью свойсва "height=". Но ещё можешь уменьшить значение толщины границы ("borderwidth=0" или "borderwidth=1"). Таким образом, атрибут большой и текст тоже.